# background-position doesn't work

Tags: css, background, css-position

I'm trying to use part of an image as volume  button.

html code

```
<div class="vol-pro-wrapper">
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="volume" class="volume"></a>
</div>
```

css code

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.volume {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-position: -2px -248px;
}
.volume:hover {
  background-position: -31px -248px;
}
.play,.pause, .previous, .next ,.volume {
  background: url(https://music.163.com/style/web2/img/frame/playbar_8.png?
 904c92305ed99579afcff04d0c63709b) no-repeat 0 9999px;
 }
```

What is really strange is that volume dosen't show as expected. But when hovered  the volume show as what i want.   What's the reason?  Thanks first!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lanhan/e2nw6c9f/)

Comment: You have background position at `0  9999px` which is practically off screen.

Comment: .volume {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-position: -31px -248px;
}
Try this style for .volume

Comment: @Dexter: this code will show the on hover state of volume control instead of normal state

Comment: I have seen this way in other websites. To be honest i didn't know why. T_T@OmriLuzon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule...

```
.play,.pause, .previous, .next ,.volume {
  background: url(https://music.163.com/style/web2/img/frame/playbar_8.png?
 904c92305ed99579afcff04d0c63709b) no-repeat 0 9999px;
 }
```

...overwrites this one (for `.volume`)...

```
.volume {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-position: -2px -248px;
}
```

..., since it comes after it.

Just change their order:

```
.play,.pause, .previous, .next ,.volume {
  background: url(https://music.163.com/style/web2/img/frame/playbar_8.png?
 904c92305ed99579afcff04d0c63709b) no-repeat 0 9999px;
 }
.volume {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-position: -2px -248px;
}
.volume:hover {
  background-position: -31px -248px;
}
```

Comment: It does work! Thanks a lot. But it still left me some questions.
You point out that .volume  is overwritten. However  in the css file, .play  .pause are both appearing before    
```
    .play,.pause, .previous, .next ,.volume {
     background: 
    url(https://music.163.com/style/web2/img/frame/playbar_8.png?
 904c92305ed99579afcff04d0c63709b) no-repeat 0 9999px;
 }
```
Why they behave different like .volume?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean, especially without seeing the corresponding code

Answer (score 0):

Change volume class in your code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  /*background-color: #555*/
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: #323231;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 30px 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.vol-pro-wrapper .volume {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-position: -2px -248px;
}

.vol-pro-wrapper .volume:hover {
  background-position: -31px -248px;
}

.btn-wrapper .play {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-position: 0 -204px;
}

.btn-wrapper .play:hover {
  background-position: -40px -204px;
}

.btn-wrapper .pause {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-position: 0 -165px;
}

.btn-wrapper .pause:hover {
  background-position: -40px -165px;
}

.btn-wrapper .previous {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background-position: 0 -130px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.btn-wrapper .previous:hover {
  background-position: -30px -130px;
}

.btn-wrapper .next {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background-position: -80px -130px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.btn-wrapper .next:hover {
  background-position: -110px -130px;
}


.play,.pause, .previous, .next ,.volume {
  background: url(https://music.163.com/style/web2/img/frame/playbar_8.png?904c92305ed99579afcff04d0c63709b) no-repeat 0 9999px;
}

#volume-slider {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <body style="height: 100%">
    <div class="container">

      <h2 class="logo">ff-player</h2>
      <div class="cover-wrapper">
        <img src="" alt="cover" class="cover">
      </div>

      <div class="vol-pro-wrapper">
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="volume" class="volume"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="previous" class="previous"></a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="play" class="play"></a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" id="next" class="next"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder how it makes thing different. what has changed after nested in .vol-pro-wrapper?